# [Java]How to read name of variable and string from java name.properties file

Tags: java, string, variables, bufferedreader

I have a code that will save a String+variable+string to a .properties file
but it saves it as String and when i load it again to program that variable is not variable anymore- it just a string.

How to do that -> load string+variable+string and load it into one variable in my java code form file name.properties?

```
String userNickname = api.getClientInfo(movedevent.getClientId()).getNickname();
String Text="[i]Welcome [/i][color=red][b]" + userNickname+ "[/b][/color][i] on channel";


Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
prop.setProperty("Text", Textregister);

            File f = new File("server.properties");
            if(!f.exists()){
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f, false), "UTF-8")), true);

            prop.store(out, "Autoconfig");
            }





        } catch (Exception io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And then load it to program.

```
 InputStream input = null;

            try {


                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("server.properties"), "UTF8"));
                // load a properties file
                prop.load(in);

                // get the property value and print it out
                Text= prop.getProperty("Textregister");
} catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (input != null) {
                    try {
                        input.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

I got *Welcome* **" + userNickname+ "** *on channel"*

but i want Welcome  **Mynickname**  on channel"

Any one can help?

Comment: Can you print the content of variable userNickname just to make sure what the actual content of the variable is? This would have to be just after setting the value.

Comment: Problem is when i put it to name.properties and then i read it. I got "Welcome Hakens on channel" but if someone else join same channel he got same message "Welcome Hakens on channel" cuz userNickname after load from name.properties its nor a variable its only String like Welcome...on channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the name at run time, you can save your text like:

```
"[i]Welcome [/i][color=red][b] {USER-NAME} [/b][/color][i] on channel"
```

And then, after reading the properties, you will have this string in the variable `Text`, so you can searc and replace it with the user that is logged in:

```
String userNickname = api.getClientInfo(movedevent.getClientId()).getNickname();
Text.replaceAll("{USER-NAME}", userNickname);
```

Note: the first parameter of replaceAll is a regex. Maybe the '{' and '}' have to be escaped with a double back slash. I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

This not work

```
String userNickname = api.getClientInfo(movedevent.getClientId()).getNickname();
Text.replaceAll("{USER-NAME}", userNickname);
```

But after i put this to String variable and next change that in my code - it works

```
String userNickname = api.getClientInfo(movedevent.getClientId()).getNickname();
String variable = Text.replaceAll("\\{USER-NAME\\}", userNickname);
```

Very big thanks Juan for helping!